# Why does a floating balloon in an accelerated train moves forward but the pendulum moves backward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If we bring a floating balloon in a accelerated train, the balloon will move forward in the same direction as the acceleration as shown in the following figure.

[image]

However if a pendulum is hung on the train ceiling, the ball moves backward. We also get moved backward in the accelerated train.

Could you explain why the floating balloon behaves differently?

Comment: see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86774/why-does-a-helium-filled-ballon-move-forward-in-a-car-when-the-car-is-accelerati

Comment: Note that this will only happen if the balloon is filled with Helium or some other gas lighter than air. Now think about this: if you release a balloon and a metal ball inside a container of water, *won't the balloon move upwards and the ball go downwards?* Why do you think is that!?

Comment: look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYRuHSfR4R8 here acceleration is radial  also  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXpURFYgR2E . The link of Christoff explains it. A matter of buoyancy. rule of thumb what floats up in air  follows the balloon track, what sinks follows the pendulum.

Comment: This has been treated extensively in Christoph's link. It would be nice, though, if you could incorporate your image into that question, though ;).