# Easy derivation of Pascal's Law

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics

I would like to know a simple derivation of [Pascal's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law), i.e. why the variation of pressure at a given point of an incompressible fluid also happens to all others.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252580/