# A trough contains a completely immersed object. On accelerating the container upwards, which direction will the object move to?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, buoyancy

While thinking intuitively, it seems quite obvious that the object displaces itself in the **downward direction**.
But, will there be a case where the **buoyant force** dominates over it's **own weight** which **may** cause the ball to rise?

(No information about the densities/masses of any object is given)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86774/why-does-a-helium-filled-balloon-move-forward-in-a-car-when-the-car-is-accelerat

Comment: Oh yes! So what I can glean from this answer is that the object will in fact always go downwards? Also, is there any rigorous way to actually prove it (ie- with force equations)? I'm unfamiliar with Lagrangian minimization, and cannot understand what the second part of the answer meant.